# Is Windows Azure compatible with the .NET 2.0 framework?

Tags: .net-2.0, azure

I have a service that was developed in the .NET 2.0 framework. It is installed in several sites and works with my application. I would like the service to be able to "report" back to me with certain information about the application. I wanted to see if Windows Azure would be an option for me to be able to store reports in a cloud db and be able to pull them when I need to. One of my main concerns is it compatible with my .NET 2.0 service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: yes. Windows Azure can run code compiled against 2.0/3.5 and 4.0. You may not have access to all of the Azure SDK (some of the libraries require 3.5), but your service should run with no modifications.

Comment: So are you telling me that I cannot use any of the libraries unless my service is a 3.5 and above? I was hoping be be able to incorporate Azure into my existing 2.0 service in order to send data to a Azure cloud db when necessary. I have tried searching for .NET 2.0 and Azure and could not find a clear answer as to whether or not I can accomplish this or not.

Comment: You should still be able to incorporate Azure into your service. Although your service is written for 2.0, the Framework on the Azure machine will be 3.5 (which runs on the 2.0 runtime). Without getting too deep into the various possible solutions, you can either recompile against 3.5 with direct references to the Azure SDK, compile against 2.0 with references to "shim" libraries that can abstract away Azure storage (handy for testing in dev environments, I might add), or if you have the intestinal fortitude you can go low-level and write a pure 2.0 assembly that consumes the REST API.

Comment: "Recompile against 3.5 with direct references to the Azure SDK" - Do you mean to convert my service to 3.5 so I can use the Azure SDK?


"compile against 2.0 with references to 'shim' libraries that can abstract away Azure storage" - My application is in Access 2000 and my service is in VB.NET 2.0, so are you saying that I would need a COM object to pass parameters into to use the Azure SDK?


"you can go low-level and write a pure 2.0 assembly that consumes the REST API" - I will have to read up on the REST API if this is an option.

Comment: Yes, one option is to change the target framework to 3.5 (doesn't change your code, just allows you to reference 3.5 assemblies from within Visual Studio). The "shim" approach would be to write another assembly (targeting 3.5) that wraps the functionality provided by the SDK assemblies and have that assembly referenced by your 2.0 service. The thing to remember here is that the only thing that's different between the 2.0 and 3.X frameworks are the assemblies; the runtime is 2.0. 4.0, on the other hand, *is* a new runtime. The REST approach is the most flexible, but is MUCH more work.