# can a web app which is created using .net framework 2.0 running on windows server 2003 be migrated to azure?

Tags: azure, .net-2.0, windows-server-2003

i have a web application which is created using .net framework 2.0 which is running on windows server 2003.is it possible to migrate that to Microsoft azure.if so does it require an entire rebuild on  azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really useful utility for this case is Azure Migration Assistant.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/migration-assistant/

It will check all your IIS sites and show you if it can be moved up to an App Service, checking target framework, port bindings, etc.

If everything is ok, it can do the migration for you.

Worst case scenario, you can move your application to Azure inside a VM.

Comment: thanks for that, i will take a look at it.just to let you know i have been using iis 6.0

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "migrate".
If you think about moving as is, you have an option to choose IaaS, where you'll just get a VM and do what you want on it. That'll give you both full control as well as full responsibility over your app.
Otherwise, if you want to avail of the PaaS offering, you'll have to make minor tweaks to your application (assuming the framework version is supported).

Comment: well i wanna move from windows server 2003 to azure

Comment: If the desire is to move to PaaS (the offering, where you don't worry about the infrastructure at all)  you sure will need to make changes to your code. @ZairHenrique's response refers to the migration assistant, which is what you'll definite need to stick with to make it simple. Good luck.

Comment: If you target an Azure AppService for example, then sure. Here is another post regarding which versions of the framework are available on Azure AppService: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144331/what-versions-of-net-are-supported-on-azure-web-sites . Here is another interesting one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442443/is-windows-azure-compatible-with-the-net-2-0-framework

Comment: oh,is it possible to convert the existing application framework to 3.5 or up?

Comment: It is possible. There are probably some breaking changes in between, but those won't be major. So you'll have to fix all those (if any) and recompile targeting the newer framework.

Comment: so if i convert the framework to a newer version.and then try to migrate from windows server 2003 to azure it should work right?

Comment: I assume by "migrate" you mean - "Deploy to" azure? Give you've done both steps, yes. On the side note, if I would be in your situation and will be sure I'm going to update the framework, I'd probably directly bump it up to the latest framework.